# Is there an adjective for mysticism?

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I don't think mystical is the adjective for mysticism. Do you just use the noun as an adjective as in "mysticism theory", "mysticism movie", "mysticism idea"?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you mean when you say *mysticism theory* or *mysticism movie*?

Comment: There are *mystical* and *mystic*.  Apart from those, you can use a preposition phrase *A movie about mysticism.*

Comment: Jack, with the possible addition of a comment that in each of the OP's three examples, a preposition phrase is the *only* option, I'd say your comment is The Answer. Why don't you promote it to one.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a good option for mysticism "about mysticism" seems to be the only viable option.